# How to force findAllBy to return array in Grails for single result?

Tags: hibernate, grails

in few places in my code I query db using `def results = Domain.findAllBySomething` and I expect an array (i use `results.size()` to determine how many results I have).
However, if findAll call results in a single object returned, it will not be returned as array but a reference to this single object.

Is there any way I could force grails to always return array, no matter how many results there are?

I'm using 2.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`findAll*` is supposed to always return a Collection - I tried the following code in 2.1:

```
def person = Person.findAllByName('kelly')
println person.size()
println person.class
println person[0].name
```

prints

```
1
class java.util.ArrayList
kelly
```

Can you add some code that shows it returning a single instance?

Comment: findAll also returns an ArrayList, so that's not the case either.

Comment: Not sure what you mean Tomas.

Comment: The findAll( 'from person where name = ? ', ['kelly'] ) command also returns an ArrayList. From the question, I assumed that this was the issue ( using FindAll vs. FindAllByName ) , but it is not.

Comment: OK - I understand. He explicitly had `findAllBySomething` so I only tested that..  Thanks!

Comment: Damn... I have gone through the code again [and it wasn't the second or third time, closer to 10th] and I've spotted a place, where instead of findlAllBy... I had findBy... Sorry guys for the misunderstanding and thanks for help.